# Is it wise to get another PhD in statistics after finishing PhD in math?

Tags: phd, career-path, changing-fields, statistics, second-degree

I am currently starting my second year of PhD study in mathematics at an institution ranked 70-80 in math in the US. In my first year, I have taken some courses in probability theory and passed two of three qualifying exams.

After taking the probability courses and since my girlfriend is pursuing a master in statistics. I found myself really interested in statistics, is it wise to get another PhD in statistics after finishing PhD in math, or should I try to apply for a PhD in statistics now?

Is it possible for me to get admitted to an good institution(ranked 30-40 in US) with only some backgrounds in math?

Comment: I have voted to reopen.  The linked to question is very general.  Since the OP has named two specific fields, the answers can be much more targeted.  The prospect of doing multiple PhDs is a common enough academic concern that there is no need to impose the restriction that there be only one such question on this site.  Moreover the OP has asked other questions, related to his title question but not covered by the linked to one.

Comment: Related: [After starting a PhD in Mathematics, I realized I am more interested in Statistics - can I transfer to a Statistics PhD?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23167/after-starting-a-phd-in-mathematics-i-realized-i-am-more-interested-in-statisti)